# How can the mentioned sentence can be shortened

Tags: grammar, sentence

文が長くて、短くする可能がありますでしょうか？(文法とか使って)

data source A, B, C あります.
以下を日本語で説明したいです。

```
"Application should get data from source A, but if source C has data available, 
then it reads data from Source C, and suppose source C does not have data, 
but source B has, then it reads data from source B"
```

上記を見ると文は結構長いだと思います。日本語で以下で書けますが、短く文で書きたいと思います。
どのように文を作れますか？

```
アプリは Source A からデータを取得するはずですが、Source Cでデータが存在すれば、
Source Cから取得しています。Source C でデータ存在しないけど、
Source B でデータ存在する場合、Source B から取得しています。
```

If I try a short sentence in English, it may be something like below:

```
Application should read data from Source A, but if Source C or Source B has data 
then it gets data from C or B by considering C as priority over B.
```

Comment: Are you asking for a translation?

Comment: @GuiImamura no. In best possible way how the sentence can be mentioned in short and still understandable, is the point.

Comment: @Manak What kind of answer do you expect? A shorter sentence in Japanese would be along the same lines with your shorter English sentence. Even if you provide a translation of it, it would then be a proofreading request. I don't really see how this question can be on topic.